# ACF's repeater field is not rendering subfields

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, advanced-custom-fields

I am writing a code where I can get notifications everytime a post is edited on a custom post type.

It is working fine, but ACF's repeater field is not rendering its subfields on the email.

I wonder what I could be doing wrong. The email comes with the exact number of rows in the post, only the fields are not being displayed.

Everything else seems to be working fine.

```
function send_mails_on_update( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{
    if ( $new_status != $old_status or 'form_caravanas' !== get_post_type( $post ) )
        return 'text/html';

    $subscribers = get_users( array ( 'role' => 'administrator' ) );
    $emails      = array ();

    foreach ( $subscribers as $subscriber )
    $emails[] = $subscriber->user_email;

    $nome = get_field('nome', $post);
    $sobrenome = get_field('sobrenome', $post);
    $ddd_celular = get_field('ddd_celular', $post);
    $email = get_field('email', $post);
    $nome_da_igreja = get_field('nome_da_igreja', $post);
    $tipo_de_transporte = get_field('tipo_de_transporte', $post);
    $cidade_e_estado_de_origem = get_field('cidade_e_estado_de_origem', $post);

    $repeater = get_field('participantes', $post);

    $participantes = '';

    if( have_rows('participantes', $post) ):
    while( have_rows('participantes', $post) ): the_row();
    $nome_participante = the_sub_field('nome', $post);
    $sobrenome_participante = the_sub_field('sobrenome', $post);
    $ddd_celular_participante = the_sub_field('telefone', $post);
    $email_participante = the_sub_field('email', $post);

    $participantes.= sprintf( '<ul>
        <li>Nome: ' . $nome_participante . '</li>
        <li>Sobrenome: ' . $sobrenome_participante . '</li>
        <li>Celular: ' . $ddd_celular_participante . '</li>
        <li>Email: ' . $email_participante . '</li>
    </ul>' ); endwhile; endif;

    $participantes.= '';

    $body = sprintf( '<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"></head><body>
    <div class="container"><p><h3>Responsável</h3></p>
    <p><strong>Nome:</strong> ' . $nome . '<br>
    <strong>Sobrenome:</strong> ' . $sobrenome . '<br>
    <strong>DDD + Celular:</strong> ' . $ddd_celular . '<br>
    <strong>Email:</strong> ' . $email . '<br>
    <strong>Nome da Igreja:</strong> ' . $nome_da_igreja . '<br>
    <strong>Tipo de Transporte:</strong> ' . $tipo_de_transporte . '<br>
    <strong>Cidade e Estado de Origem:</strong> ' . $cidade_e_estado_de_origem . '<br>
    </p>
    <p><h3>Participantes</h3></p>
    <p>' . $participantes . '</p>
    </div></body></html>' );


    wp_mail( $emails, 'A caravana "' . get_the_title( $post ) . '" foi atualizada!', $body );
}
```

Comment: Is `$post` the `$post->ID` ?

Comment: Hi @TyBailey, I tried `$post->ID` but it made no difference.

Comment: What is the `$post` variable you are passing as a parameter? Is it the post object or...? Also, which action/filter are you hooking into to execute this function?

Comment: Yes `$post` is `$post->ID` and the action is `add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'send_mails_on_update', 10, 3 );`

Comment: Is everything working except the repeater's fields?

Comment: Yes, everything is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that `participantes` is the name of the repeater. Then, remove the `$post` variable in every `the_sub_field()`.

Change

```
$nome_participante = the_sub_field('nome', $post);
$sobrenome_participante = the_sub_field('sobrenome', $post);
$ddd_celular_participante = the_sub_field('telefone', $post);
$email_participante = the_sub_field('email', $post);
```

To

```
$nome_participante = the_sub_field('nome');
$sobrenome_participante = the_sub_field('sobrenome');
$ddd_celular_participante = the_sub_field('telefone');
$email_participante = the_sub_field('email');
```

You already mentioned which repeater's values to fetch(and you are in that repeater's while loop) so you don't need to insert that again on the sub field.

Also, you might need to use `get_sub_field()` and not `the_sub_field()`. The difference is that `the_sub_field()` echoes the value and `get_sub_field()` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! Removing `$post` didn't work, but using `get_sub_field()` instead did the trick. :)

Comment: The same happens with `the_field()` and `get_field()`